# Postman request returns 201, OkHttp3 request returns 400

Tags: android, api, post, okhttp

I need to send data to API and I use OkHttp 3.9.1

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
String path = "/api/mobileinspector";
Request.Builder builder = new Request.Builder();
URI url = URI.create(ApiManager.apiURL + path);
MultipartBody.Builder builder = new MultipartBody.Builder();
builder.addFormDataPart("MobileInspector[fio]", fio);
builder.addFormDataPart("MobileInspector[email]", email);
builder.addFormDataPart("MobileInspector[phone]", phone);
builder.addFormDataPart("MobileInspector[description]", description);
builder.addFormDataPart("MobileInspector[address]", address);
builder.addFormDataPart("MobileInspector[category]", category.toString());
MultipartBody body = builder.build();
builder.addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
    .addHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")
    .url(url.toURL())
    .post(body);
response = client.newCall(builder.build()).execute();
```

API returns 400, that means API did not recognized data.
I tried same request in Postiman and it worked fine, returned 201 as expected.

I captured http requests from postman and from simulator with wireshark. I can't find any differences in these requests:

OkHttp made this request:

> 8G^|E@@`}P~r#]'z@
>
> m'<8POST /api/mobileinspector HTTP/1.1 Accept: application/json
>   Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
>   boundary=28ede98e-87b6-4701-b587-57bbcdccb802 Content-Length: 842
>   Host: API_CORRECT_IP Connection: Keep-Alive Accept-Encoding: gzip
>   User-Agent: okhttp/3.9.1
>
> --28ede98e-87b6-4701-b587-57bbcdccb802 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="MobileInspector[fio]" Content-Length: 3
>
> 123
>   --28ede98e-87b6-4701-b587-57bbcdccb802 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="MobileInspector[email]" Content-Length: 11
>
> 123@eqw.sda
>   --28ede98e-87b6-4701-b587-57bbcdccb802 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="MobileInspector[phone]" Content-Length: 7
>
> 7232321
>   --28ede98e-87b6-4701-b587-57bbcdccb802 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="MobileInspector[description]" Content-Length: 5
>
> 21321
>   --28ede98e-87b6-4701-b587-57bbcdccb802 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="MobileInspector[address]" Content-Length: 7
>
> 2332121
>   --28ede98e-87b6-4701-b587-57bbcdccb802 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="MobileInspector[category]" Content-Length: 1
>
> 2
>   --28ede98e-87b6-4701-b587-57bbcdccb802--

And Postman made this one:

> 8G^|E@@`}Pa8@
>
> Y'<3POST /api/mobileinspector HTTP/1.1 cache-control: no-cache
>   Postman-Token: 8e425452-a60d-4209-8868-acf9ebc9986b User-Agent:
>   PostmanRuntime/7.1.1 Accept: */* Host: API_CORRECT_IP accept-encoding:
>   gzip, deflate content-type: multipart/form-data;
>   boundary=--------------------------067684848634261464344219
>   content-length: 841 Connection: keep-alive
>
> ----------------------------067684848634261464344219 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="MobileInspector[fio]"
>
> test
>   ----------------------------067684848634261464344219 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="MobileInspector[email]"
>
> test@example.com
>   ----------------------------067684848634261464344219 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="MobileInspector[address]"
>
> address
>   ----------------------------067684848634261464344219 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="MobileInspector[phone]"
>
> 12312312
>   ----------------------------067684848634261464344219 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="MobileInspector[category]"
>
> 1
>   ----------------------------067684848634261464344219 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="MobileInspector[description]"
>
> no description
>   ----------------------------067684848634261464344219--

Comment: content-type: multipart/mixed vs. multipart/form-data. My guess is your server does not support multipart/mixed.

Comment: Hi why addHeader("Accept", "application/json") ?

Comment: @PankajKantPatel hi, because I need response in JSON. Accept header is about response format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two parts differ a lot:

okhttp:

> m'<8POST /api/mobileinspector HTTP/1.1 Accept: application/json Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=28ede98e-87b6-4701-b587-57bbcdccb802 Content-Length: 842 Host: API_CORRECT_IP Connection: Keep-Alive Accept-Encoding: gzip User-Agent: okhttp/3.9.1

Postman:

> Y'<3POST /api/mobileinspector HTTP/1.1 cache-control: no-cache Postman-Token: 8e425452-a60d-4209-8868-acf9ebc9986b User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.1.1 Accept: / Host: API_CORRECT_IP accept-encoding: gzip, deflate content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------067684848634261464344219 content-length: 841 Connection: keep-alive

Postman sends content as `multipart/form-data`, while okhttp sets `multipart/mixed`. This issue is almost certainly related to the content-type that is unexpected by API.

Try setting the builder like:

```
RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
      .type(MultipartBody.FORM)
      // ...
      .build();
```

Comment: Yes, @eugen-pechanec pointed this. Please add solution to your answer: builder.setType(MultipartBody.FORM);